# Is there a way to detect msg reactions on a specific msg?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a new system on my server, i need a way to detect reactions on some msgs, so the user will react to run a function like send msg or something else...

I tried to use reaction collector, but i can't deal with it, this method will not gonna work with old msgs.
I need something simple, to build my system on, so i can use different functions like `message.channel.send` or `message.guild.createChannel`, with the ability to detect the msg content, this one is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reaction collectors can indeed work on messages that have already been sent prior to the client's login. However, these messages must be kept track of and fetched.

**Example System** (did not test, just an example)

`messages.json`:

```
[
  {
    "guild": "guildIDhere",
    "channel": "channelIDhere",
    "message": "messageIDhere",
    "filter": "(reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id !== client.user.id;",
    "options": { "max": 1 },
    "callback": "collected => console.log(collected);"
  }
]
```

`index.js`:

```js
const messages = require('./messages.json'); // Path may vary
const fs = require('fs');

client.on('ready', () => {
  const deleteQueue = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    const guild = client.guilds.get(messages[i].guild);
    if (!guild) {
      deleteQueue.push(i);
      continue;
    }

    const channel = guild.channels.get(messages[i].channel);
    if (!channel) {
      deleteQueue.push(i);
      continue;
    }

    const message = channel.fetchMessage(messages[i].message);
    if (!message) {
      deleteQueue.push(i);
      continue;
    }

    message.createReactionCollector(eval(messages[i].filter), messages[i].options)
      .then(eval(messages[i].callback))
      .catch(console.error);

  }

  if (deleteQueue.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < deleteQueue.length; i++) messages.splice(deleteQueue[i], 1);
    fs.writeFileSync('./message.json', JSON.stringify(messages));
    console.log(`${deleteQueue.length} message(s) are no longer available.`);
  }
});
```

Creating a collector later on:

```js
message.channel.send('React with :smile:')
  .then(m => {
    const filter = ...;
    const options = ...;
    const callback = ...;
    m.createReactionCollector(filter, options)
      .then(callback)
      .catch(...);

    messages.push({
      guild: message.guild.id,
      channel: message.channel.id,
      message: message.id,
      filter: `${filter}`,
      options: options,
      callback: `${callback}`
    });

    fs.writeFileSync('./messages.json', JSON.stringify(messages));
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: oh, so you should define the message before using the collector

Comment: Exactly. It's just a matter of keeping track of the messages you need. A database would be a **much** better option than a json file, but there's so many options and different usage for each so that's why I didn't include that in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use RethinkDB to save messages.
RethinkDB is a Realtime Database, and a simple way to detect realtime messages.

https://www.rethinkdb.com/